# Items Update on second click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am working on a project in which we enter an email and that is checked with the emails present in different tables of the database. Depending upon tables in which the entered email is present I want to display a list of check boxes in a dialog box on clicking a button. My problem is the names of check boxes get updated only on the second click and on further clicks the order of names change. I am not able to figure out this and spent many hours in same. Please help!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public EditText et;
public Main2Activity act;
private String s;
private String[] st = {"","",""};
private int i,j;
private Boolean x;
private String url1 = "http://192.168.56.1:80/axis/results.json";
private String url2 = "http://192.168.56.1:80/hdfc/results.json";
private String url3 = "http://192.168.56.1:80/sbi/results.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String[] items= {"","",""};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //mail entered into the edittext
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    j=0;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
// on click
public void makeJsonArrayRequest(View view) {
    j=0;
    s=et.getText().toString();//email to string
    JsonArrayRequest req1 = new JsonArrayRequest(url1,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {

                       for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String email = person.getString("email");
                           if(email.equals(s)){
                               System.out.println("Axis");
                                //if present in the table add to list
                               addItem("AXIS");
                               }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    JsonArrayRequest req2 = new JsonArrayRequest(url2,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String email = person.getString("email");
                            if(email.equals(s)) {
                                System.out.println("HDFC");
                                addItem("HDFC");
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    JsonArrayRequest req3 = new JsonArrayRequest(url3,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String email = person.getString("email");
                            if(email.equals(s)){
                                System.out.println("SBI");
                               addItem("SBI");}
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req1);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req2);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req3);
    dialogadd();
}


public void addItem(String s)
{
    items[j]=s;
    j++;
}

public void dialogadd()
{
    Dialog dialog;


    final ArrayList itemsSelected = new ArrayList();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select banks you want to connect to: ");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                    boolean isSelected) {
                    if (isSelected) {
                        itemsSelected.add(selectedItemId);
                    } else if (itemsSelected.contains(selectedItemId)) {
                        itemsSelected.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));
                    }
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Done!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Your logic when OK button is clicked
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();}

}
```

here is the log cat
[logcat](http://pastebin.com/mhrxM32v)

**on first click** 
[image: on first click]

**on second click**
[image: on second click]

**on third click**
[image: on third click]

Comment: call dialogadd method after completion of all three network call completed

Comment: yeah..done that @USKMobility, +1 and a lot thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req1); // this will take some time get data
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req2); // even this will take some time get data
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req3); //last this also will take some time get data
dialogadd(); // but this is an instant call. which will show the dialog, since previous all three call are pending your data get shown unless they complete.
```

solution : use below call to show the dialog

```
JsonArrayRequest req3 = new JsonArrayRequest(url3,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String email = person.getString("email");
                            if(email.equals(s)){
                                System.out.println("SBI");
                               addItem("SBI");}
               // use this last call show dialog 
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Advice

> use Future request in volley, i think wt you need is synchronous call one after another

Comment: Awesome explanation +1, I tried and it worked fine! Thank you!